# Ant design form not validating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, antd

So I was trying to follow the docs, and came up with this:

Here's a simple example:

```
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  return (
    <Form form={form} onFinish={(data) => console.log(data)}>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "test message" }]}
        label="test"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

along with a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-bhabha-q0i7c?file=/src/App.tsx:23-417)

The expected behavior is for the `Form.Item` to render a red warning like this one here:

[image]

But no such thing happens. `onFinish` says that form data is an empty object, and the validation doesn't run. So I must be missing smth. Any idea what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `name` prop for `Form.Item` component.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  return (
    <Form form={form} onFinish={(data) => console.log(data)}>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "test message" }]}
        name="username"
        label="test"
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Log:

```sh
async-validator: 
(1) ["'username' is required"]
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. Damn that's confusing. Is it mentioned in the docs?